# Mongoose find().or hangs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

New to mongodb. I am trying to make a multi field search query. When I run the below code it correctly returns results based on the keyword.

```
var re = new RegExp(req.query.keyword, 'i');
Company.find({ 'name': { $regex: re }}, 
    function (err, company) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(company);
})
```

However when I try to use `find().or` using this code, my API just hangs then times out with no error.

```
var re = new RegExp(req.query.keyword, 'i');
Company.find().or([{ 'name': { $regex: re }}, { 'url': { $regex: re }}], 
    function (err, company) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(company);
})
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Query.or`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-or) doesn't take callback function as a parameter, so you must call [`exec`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) to execute the query

```
Company.find()
    .or([{ 'name': { $regex: re }}, { 'url': { $regex: re }}])
    .exec(function (err, company) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(company);
    })
```